# Extract ajax functionality from wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone list the files required to maintain ajax calls from wp-admin folder. I will be deleting wp-admin folder from my production site but want to retain the ajax functionality.

Comment: I wonder, why is it so?

Comment: Why the .... are you deleting `wp-admin`?

Comment: Better security, my stage instance is what I use for content population, and i dont really need wp-admin on prod!
and the main reason... i shall satisfy the demands of my client :|